# How to sort List<Object> by long field

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, java-stream

```
List<DetailsDescription> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.add(
     new DetailsDescription(((Date) row.getObject("alarm_start_timestamp")).getTime()));

result.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(DetailsDescription::getStartTimestamp)
               .reversed())
               .limit(PAGE_SIZE)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hello guys!

I have couple of rows in my List and there is timestamp which I would like to sort by. The problem is that Comparator need an int and I can not cast long (which is date) because if I do I will cut some last digits. Code works however sorting is inaccurate (it cut last digits).

It might help you understand:

```
result.stream().sorted((a,b)->a.getStartTimestamp() - b.getStartTimestamp()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And the error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int
```

Comment: What is the issue with sorting by `Comparator.comparing(DetailsDescription::getStartTimestamp)`?

Comment: Date already implements Comparable

Comment: @daniu I use noSQL datebase and I can not sorty by date there so I would like to do it here in java. Dates are actually put as long.

Comment: @user7 Could you please explain me more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make use of [`Comparator.comparingLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingLong-java.util.function.ToLongFunction-):

```
result.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(DetailsDescription:: getStartTimestamp)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code would work.

Comment: Still does not work. In some records it is not sorted and timestamp does not decrease. I am not sure if Cassandra make some troubles.

Comment: @Tom This is the solution to the problem you posted in your question, given `DetailsDescription:: getStartTimestamp` actually returns a `long`. If you are not seeing the expected behavior, then the problem lies somewhere else.